# Run commands on remote server with asyncssh

Tags: python, bash, ssh

I'm trying to check how much space i have on my remote server,
so i'm using df command. 
But i have no idea why i can't run it with asyncssh
Only one command witch i can run is ls.

That is what i'm trying to do

```py
res = await conn.run('df')
print(res.stdout)
```

And i get:

```
Command not found
```

But! when i'm trying

```py
res = await conn.run('ls')
print(res.stdout)
```

I get:

```
cache
datasets
dvc-cache
home
...
```

```py
import asyncssh


client_key = asyncssh.read_private_key(RSA_KEY)

    async with asyncssh.connect(
        client_factory=None,
        host=SERVER_HOST,
        username=SERVER_USERNAME,
        port=SERVER_PORT,
        client_keys=[client_key]
    ) as conn:
        res = await conn.run('df')
        print(res.stdout)
```

Comment: Did you try with full path? e.g. /bin/df

Comment: @Pitto, 'df' doesn't support path. But 'cd path' or 'pwd' don't work as well

Comment: What kind of system is the remote computer? What operating system does it run?

Comment: @Kenster, it is file storage without bash on it. I can't even check os. But i can can 'df' on it throw my terminal

Comment: I'm not a python programmer, but your asyncssh code may be opening what ssh calls an "exec" or "command" channel. If the device that you're connecting to isn't a general-purpose computer, it may not support exec channels properly. Try using the `ssh` command-line utility to run something like `ssh user@remotehost 'df'` and see if it works.

Comment: @Kenster, yes it works. I guess it is some asyncssh lib problem. Thank you anyway

Comment: If you ssh normally into the box the command works? Which storage is it?